# Count Group Ordinal in LINQ to Dataset

Tags: ado.net, linq-to-dataset

I have an old FoxPro program that does a SQL query which includes the following:

```
            SELECT  Region,                        
                    Year AS yr_qtr,                  
                    SUM(Stock) AS inventory
```

**...

```
                   COUNT(Rent) AS rent_ct     
            FROM
```

**...

```
            GROUP   BY Region, Year           
            ORDER   BY Region, Year
            INTO    CURSOR tmpCrsr
```

The query is against a .DBF table file, and includes data from an Excel file.  I've used both to populate an enumeration of user-defined objects in my C# program.  (Not sure .AsEnumerable is needed or not.)  I then attempt to use LINQ to Dataset to query the list of user objects and create the same result set:

```
var rslt1 = from rec in recs_list //.AsEnumerable()
            group rec by new {rec.Region, rec.Year} into grp
            select new
{
    RegName = grp.Key.Region,
    yr_qtr = grp.Key.Year,
    inventory = grp.Sum(s => s.Stock),
    // ...
    rent_count = grp.Count(r => r.Rent != null)
};
```

This gives me the warning that "*The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'decimal' is never equal to 'null' of type 'decimal'*" for the Count() of the Rent column.

This makes sense, but then how do I do a count exclusive of the rows that have a value of .NULL. for that column in the FoxPro table (or NULL in any SQL database table, for that matter)?  I can't do a null test of a decimal value.

Comment: What is the type of `r.Rent`? (I can't see how you'd get that warning with the code you have.)

Comment: Probably you need `decimal?` instead of `decimal`

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be "Rent != null".  Changed above.  Rent is decimal.  What does "decimal?" with question mark do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If rent is based off of a column which is **not** a nullable value, then checking for null makes no sense which I believe the compiler accurately shows. Change the line to

```
rent_count = grp.Count(r => r.Rent != 0)
```

instead.

For if the code is actuall nullable such as:

```
Decimal? rent;
```

That would make checking rent against null valid. If that is the case then the line would be:

```
rent_count = grp.Count(r => (r.Rent ?? 0) != 0)
```

where [null coalesding operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) ?? can be used. Which states if r.rent is null, use the value 0 (or any value you want technically) for r.Rent. in the next process.

Comment: Thanks.  Robert Harvey had mentioned the use of "?", for nullable, above.  Your formulation with the null-coalescing operator makes it usable in the Count().